# SciPy.sparse iterative solvers: No sparse right hand side support?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

It seems like the iterative solvers of `scipy.sparse.linalg` do not support the sparse matrix data types of `scipy.sparse` as a right hand side of the equation system (whereas the direct solver does). Consider the following short example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.sparse
import scipy.sparse.linalg

# Construct a random sparse but regular matrix A
A = scipy.sparse.rand(50,50,density=0.1)+scipy.sparse.coo_matrix(np.diag(np.random.rand(50,)))

# Construct a random sparse right hand side
b = scipy.sparse.rand(50,1,density=0.1).tocsc()

ud = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A,b) # Works as indented
ui = scipy.sparse.linalg.bicg(A,b)[0] # ValueError: A and b have incompatible dimensions
```

The shapes seem to be correct though:

```
print(A.shape)
print(b.shape)
```

returns

```
(50, 50)
(50, 1)
```

Defining b as a dense `ndarray` however works

```
b = scipy.sparse.rand(50,1,density=0.1).todense()
```

It would be very surprising to me if there would be no support for sparse right hand sides (as arise in FEM for example) although the documentation requests `b` to be of type `{array, matrix}`.

So what am I doing wrong here or why would this be unsupported?

Comment: The docs says `matrix or array` for `b`, not `sparse`. The error is issued by `linalg.utils.make_system`.

Comment: I knew that (as i've written) and it does not answer any of the questions. Why would there be no support for sparse right hand sides?

Comment: None of the sparse solvers in scipy support multiple right-hand sides, so `b` would have to be rank-1 anyway. Given that restriction, my guess is that the devs considered it unlikely that `b` would ever be so long and sparse that it couldn't be represented as a dense array. More fundamentally, I doubt that the underlying SuperLU solver will accept a sparse matrix for `b`.

Comment: Digging further into the code, I find that the underlying fortran code is based on `netlib2` as documented in 1993 http://www.netlib.org/templates/templates.pdf.  That uses simple vector `b` and `x`, and `A` is transformed into a LinearOperator (basically `A.dot(X)`).  That's why `A` can be array, matrix or sparse - anything that implements `dot`.

Comment: The Python portion of the code could apply `todense` to `b` at any point.  But avoiding that will require changes to the Fortran code, changing `B` (array, dimension N) to a pair of smaller arrays, one representing the nonzero values, the other their indices.  This would be a fundamental rewrite, not a hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A two-part approach:

- wrap your `A` in a scipy.sparse
  [scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator.html)
  (easy)
- patch the 
  [lsmr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr.html)
  solver to use it (took some debugging).

The idea of LinearOperator is easy and powerful: it's a virtual linear operator,
or actually two:

```
Aop = Linop( A )  # see below
A.dot(x) -> Aop.matvec(x)
A.T.dot(y) -> Aop.rmatvec(y)
x = solver( Aop, b ... )  # uses matvec and rmatvec, not A.dot A.T.dot
```

Here `matvec` and `rmatvec` can do anything (within reason).
For example, they could linearize horrible nonlinear equations
near args `x` and `y` of any type whatever.
Unfortunately `aslinearoperator` doesn't work asis for sparse `x`.
The doc suggests two ways of implementing `LinearOperator`, but

> Whenever something can be done in two ways, someone will be confused.

Anyway, `Linop` below works with sparse `x` -- with a patched `lsmr.py`,
under [gist.github.com/denis-bz](https://gist.github.com/denis-bz) .
Other sparse iterative solvers ? Don't know.

---

If what you really want to do is:
minimize |A x - b|
and also keep |x| small, a.k.a. regularization, in the L1 or L2 norm

then you should definitely look at
[scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html) .
It targets different corners of
Speed - Accuracy - Problems - People (SAPP) space
than scipy.sparse.isolve .
I've found scikit-learn solid, pleasant, pretty well-documented,
but haven't compared the two on real problems.

How big, how sparse are your problems ? Could you point to test cases on the web ?

---

```
""" Linop( A ): .matvec .rmatvec( sparse vecs )
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator.html
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr.html
"""

from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator  # $scipy/sparse/linalg/interface.py

__version__ = "2015-12-24 dec  denis + safe_sparse_dot"


#...............................................................................
class Linop( LinearOperator ):  # subclass ?
    """ Aop = Linop( scipy sparse matrix A )
        ->  Aop.matvec(x) = A dot x, x ndarray or sparse
            Aop.rmatvec(x) = A.T dot x
        for scipy.sparse.linalg solvers like lsmr
    """

    def __init__( self, A ):
        self.A = A

    def matvec( self, x ):
        return safe_sparse_dot( self.A, x )

    def rmatvec( self, y ):
        return safe_sparse_dot( self.A.T, y )

        # LinearOperator subclass should implement at least one of _matvec and _matmat.
    def _matvec( self, b ):
        raise NotImplementedError( "_matvec" )

        # not _matvec only:
        # $scipy/sparse/linalg/interface.py
        # def matvec(self, x):
        #     x = np.asanyarray(x)  <-- kills sparse x, should raise an error

    def _rmatvec( self, b ):
        raise NotImplementedError( "_rmatvec" )

    @property
    def shape( self ):
        return self.A.shape


def safe_sparse_dot( a, b ):
    """ -> a * b or np.dot(a, b) """
        # from sklearn
    if sparse.issparse(a) or sparse.issparse(b):
        try:
            return a * b
        except ValueError:  # dimension mismatch: print shapes
            print "error: %s %s  *  %s %s" % (
                    type(a).__name__, a.shape,
                    type(b).__name__, b.shape )
            raise
    else:
        return np.dot(a, b)

#...........................................................................
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from lsmr import lsmr  # patched $scipy/sparse/linalg/lsmr.py

    np.set_printoptions( threshold=20, edgeitems=10, linewidth=100, suppress=True,
        formatter = dict( float = lambda x: "%.2g" % x ))

        # test sparse.rand A m n, x n 1, b m 1
    m = 10
    n = 100
    density = .1
    bdense = 0
    seed = 0
    damp = 1

        # to change these params in sh or ipython, run this.py  a=1  b=None  c=[3] ...
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        exec( arg )

    np.random.seed(seed)

    print "\n", 80 * "-"
    paramstr = "%s  m %d  n %d  density %g  bdense %d  seed %d  damp %g " % (
            __file__, m, n, density, bdense, seed, damp )
    print paramstr

    A = sparse.rand( m, n, density, format="csr", random_state=seed )
    x = sparse.rand( n, 1, density, format="csr", random_state=seed )
    b = sparse.rand( m, 1, density, format="csr", random_state=seed )
    if bdense:
        b = b.toarray().squeeze()  # matrix (m,1) -> ndarray (m,)

    #...........................................................................
    Aop = Linop( A )
        # aslinearoperator( A ): not for sparse x

        # check Aop matvec rmatvec --
    Ax = Aop.matvec( x )
    bA = Aop.rmatvec( b )
    for nm in "A Aop x b Ax bA ".split():
        x = eval(nm)
        print "%s: %s %s " % (nm, x.shape, type(x))
    print ""

    print "lsmr( Aop, b )"

    #...........................................................................
    xetc = lsmr( Aop, b, damp=damp, show=1 )
    #...........................................................................

    x, istop, niter, normr, normar, norma, conda, normx = xetc
    x = getattr( x, "A", x ) .squeeze()
    print "x:", x.shape, x

    #     print "lsmr( A, b ) -- Valueerror in $scipy/sparse/linalg/interface.py"
    #     xetc = lsmr( A, b, damp=damp, show=1 )  # Valueerror

    safe_sparse_dot( A, b.T )  # ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the way to go for now! Still don't get why the `scipy.sparse.linalg`'s direct solver `spsolve` supports sparse right hand sides while the iterative solvers don't... although in this case the problem size is actually not too big to store it dense.

Comment: @Christoph90, there's just not enough demand for sparse rhs; 99 % are "not too big to store dense". And the patched lsmr is so far not worth the bother.

Comment: I'm not a developer on `scipy.sparse.linalg` but I can give some indication for why it's likely not supported. The solution returned from an iterative solve is _very_ likely to be dense. These algorithms repeatedly call the matrix-vector product function. Every time you do a matrix-vector product you fill-in more nonzero entries, the new nonzero entries are determined by doing a single step of a breadth-first-search. Thus if the matrix has the "strong-hall" property you are guaranteed a dense output after enough iterations, and all following iterations will be fully dense.

Comment: @Reid.Atcheson, possible, thanks. But what if you demand / maintain sparsity, `x[ abs(x) < tiny ] = 0` after each iteration ? Afaik (which is not very far) L1 optimizers / Lasso do this.  Also, what's the "strong-hall" property ? Thanks

Comment: I've never tried thresholding like that, so I don't know from personal experience if that would work. I can tell though that it is a nonlinear operation, and most iterative solvers - CG,GMRES,BiCGSTAB explicitly require linearity of the input operator.

It might work on some matrices where there is exponential decay property of the entries of its inverse, so that the nonlinear operation is a small perturbation from a linear one. But I've never tried.

Comment: The strong hall property is also called "irreducible" but I avoided that term because it is very overloaded and so doing web search for it turns up a lot of unrelated definitions.

It's a property mostly used when figuring out sparse factorizations like LU or Cholesky. It basically means that if you take the graph of a sparse matrix you can reach any node by repeatedly applying breadth-first-search from any starting node. A consequence of this is that the inverse of a Strong-Hall sparse matrix is completely dense.